# Matplotlib crashes when importing pyplot in Blender

Tags: python, matplotlib, blender

I know this question has been asked many times before but I cannot find a solution that works for me. I'm running Python 3.5.3 under Blender 2.79 in Windows 10. As I require Blender 2.79, upgrading the Python version is not possible.

I've installed matplotlib and I can import it. However, when I try to import pyplot (e.g. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`), I get a crash to desktop with no error messages of any kind. This happens if I run Python externally or from inside Blender. The weird thing is that I was able to avoid this by changing backends to agg (`matplotlib.use('agg')`) and this is still working in a previous installation (so I know it's possible to get this to work !), but not in a separate, new installation of Blender. I've tried other backends but they make no difference.

The exact procedure I've tried is as follows :

- Downloaded Blender 2.79 from a [zip file](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) (I'm using Windows 10) and unpacked it (call this directory /Blender/)
- In /Blender/2.79/python/bin I run the command `./python -m ensurepip`
- In /Blender/2.79/python/scripts I run `pip3 install --upgrade pip --user`. This gives me pip3 version 20.2.4
- In the same directory I run `pip3 install --target="/Blender/2.79/python/lib/site-packages" matplotlib --upgrade`. The "upgrade" switch is to prevent warnings that the "/bin" directory exists. Doesn't make any difference if I remove it, there's no existing installation of matplotlib. This gives me matplotlib version 3.0.3
- Finally I start Python by `/Blender/2.79/python/bin/python.exe`, and do the above mentioned importmatplotlib.pyplot command which causes the crash.

I've tried this from a completely fresh installation of Blender, which comes with no existing external modules installed. Could there be some conflict with other Python modules elsewhere ? How would I go about diagnosing what's going on ?

Thanks for any ideas !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED ! I remembered I found the solution months ago, but stupidly wrote down the answer in the wrong file...

The problem is that matplotlib is looking for a file that doesn't exist. In c:/users/me/.matplotlib (a hidden file), there's a file ""fontlist-vXXX.json", where XXX is the version number. This is set in line 951 of the file "font_manager.py", located in /python/lib/site-packages/matplotlib. In my case, the font_manager was looking for version 300 but the actual file was 310. Changing the version number in the font_manager.py made everything work correctly.